# react native - passing option allowNamespaces to babel typescript plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, babeljs

I would like to use TensorFlow in react native - managed flow by expo. When I use the https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-react-native bridge, I am getting an error when running on android that babel needs the option allowNamespaces set to true for @babel/plugin-transform-typescript.

So I changed the babel.config.js to:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
      {
        allowNamespaces: true
      }
    ]
  };
};
```

But now I am getting the error `Error: [BABEL] /node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js: .allowNamespaces is not a valid Plugin property`, so it adds the dot in the beggining.

I tried to put it into `.babelrc` but still the same. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did more tries and finally, `.babelrc` configuration is passed correctly:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript", { "allowNamespaces": true }]
    ]
}
```